# Limitations of indirectly comparing meta-analysis Effect Sizes (ES)

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm reviewing meta-analyses (MAs) for a college assignment and am trying to locate a reference to help me make sense of why indirectly comparing different treatment Effect Sizes (ESs) is potentially problematic.

To use an example to explain what I mean by 'indirectly comparing different treatment ESs': One MA  generates an average ES from five studies that compare Treatment A to Waitlist controls, and say the ES is Hedges g = 0.80 in favour of Treatment A. In the same MA they generate an average ES from five different studies that compare Treatment B to Waitlist controls, and say the ES is Hedges g = 0.60 in favour of Treatment B.

This MA then statistically compares the 0.80 ES for Treatment A to the 0.60 ES for Treatment B, and states that the results indicates that Treatment A is more effective than Treatment B.

My understanding is that this is an **indirect** way of comparing these treatments to each other, because neither treatment was actually compared directly with the other - only their ESs when compared to different waitlist control conditions was compared.

My understanding is that the ideal situation would be that Treatment A and Treatment B would be **directly** compared to one another in a single study and then hopefully lots of single studies do the same to provide enough data for a MA; and for my research focus I have found a number of meta-analyses that have found such studies and generated ESs for these direct comparisons. However, I am trying to find a reference so that I can (1) understand the limitations of the **indirect** way of comparing ESs and (2) have a justifiably rationale why I would exclude the MAs that only carried out the **indirect** comparisons (or perhaps I shouldn't be excluding them at all?).

Comment: Try searching for network meta-analysis also known as multiple treatment comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mdewey, I had come across one network meta-analysis related to the topic I am reviewing but it has been flagged as having flaws by other authors (e.g. miscategorisation of treatments). So I am stuck with meta-analyses that have either (a) generated separate ESs and then compared them, and (b) meta-analyses that have directly compared two treatments. I'm still searching for a quotable reference that states why the indirect comparisons are not ideal.

Comment: Direct comparisons come from randomised trials with all the benefits that entails, indirect ones do not so they are more likely to be subject to bias. There is nothing wrong with them, that is why we have NMA but their limitations need to be recognised.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply.